# Video borders with cursor position

Tags: css, border-layout, cursor-position

I am grabbing a video using ajax and jQuery, and making a place where to be displayed called "displayMedia":

```
<div class="displayMedia getCursorPosition" style="width: auto; height: auto; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: red;" align="center"></div>
```

And I would like to make borders for that video, of course videos have different dimensions, so I am trying to make borders to calculate the X and Y for the cursor position, that will allow me where to place a watermark for that video:

```
       $('.getCursorPosition').on( "mousemove", function( event ) {              
    $( ".displayCursorPosition" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
});
```

The problem is the borders are not set correctly.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, could you provide a fiddle or snippet of your code? Without your HTML, CSS, and anything else necessary, it will be really difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xgej7cpe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code to work with your newly provided HTML:

**For responsive video:**

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="displayMedia getCursorPosition" style="width: auto; height: auto; border-style: solid; border-width: 5px; border-color: red;" align="center">
  <video controls>
    <source src="http://www.tutoriels-video.fr/videos/Serveur-dedie/tutoriel_connexion_ssh.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

**For fixed-size video: (see comments in CSS for details)**

```css
.displayMedia {
  /* only set one width or height, set the other to auto - this will maintain the video aspect ratio */
  width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
video {
  /* if you set the height of .displayMedia to a fixed size and the width to auto, then change the width of this element to 'auto' and the height to '100%', and the display to 'inline-block' */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="displayMedia getCursorPosition">
  <video controls>
    <source src="http://www.tutoriels-video.fr/videos/Serveur-dedie/tutoriel_connexion_ssh.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

I suggest you reference [this article](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) for some more details on how this works. I provided this link earlier and it shows how I was able to set the styling on the `<video>` element. It may also help you with any more situations that you might encounter.

Comment: well I am not using iframe, that is only an example, I am using a video in between div: <div>video</div>

Comment: So why did you give me a fiddle with an iframe?

Comment: how can I include a video?

Comment: @OumAlaa I updated my answer to match the element. I suggest the article I posted in the answer so you can learn more about what's happening here.

Comment: It works, awesome, https://jsfiddle.net/xgej7cpe/4/, however if I point out the cursor at the top left corner, I should get the X=0 and Y=0, but some big numbers like X=8 and Y=30